# I changed to 4 spaces instead of tabs, how do I indent?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I copy and paste code it gets wonky and now fixing it is no longer a case of backspacing a single tab, now its a case of backspacing 4 spaces. How do I easily maintain indentation now that I have switched to 4 spaces instead of a tab?

Comment: Use shift-tab to unindent?

Comment: @crashmstr only seems to work for tabs not 4 spaces, thanks anyways

Comment: Strange, I tried in mine and it did work. Are you using Smart tabs?

Comment: @crashmstr yes i am, shift tab doesn't do anything, maybe its va-assist or some add-on doing it for you, or maybe its a setting you can set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open sublime text 2 and select one 4 spaces and press ctrl + D if on windows till you select all 4 spaced indents. Now press delete key and press tab key. Done! May check out this page http://css-tricks.com/changing-spaces-tabs-sublime-text/

Comment: are you suggesting I program in sublime instead of MSVS2010?

Comment: Okay I see where you are going with this, its a good answer. I think however I will work in tabs again and then convert to spaces when I need to, maybe I will use sublime to do that. thanks